# Why is this error being thrown? (Python 3, Pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, runtime-error

In my game, pertinent code found [here](http://pastebin.com/phMnFase), and also at the end of this post, this error is being thrown when evaluating:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\GitHub\Tarbeyon\level.py", line 60, in <module>
    level.parseLevel() # Building the level
  File "C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\GitHub\Tarbeyon\level.py", line 47, in parseLevel
    self.block[name] = Fountain((x, y), name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.add(*groups)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 142, in add
    self.add(*group)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 142, in add
    self.add(*group)
TypeError: add() argument after * must be a sequence, not int
[Finished in 2.8s]
```

What am I doing wrong? I can provide the code for the fountain, which seems to be the class that is glitching.

Fountain Class:

```
class Fountain(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def init(self, pos, name):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.add(constant.blocks)
        self.add(constant.fountains)

        self.name = name

        self.particles = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Images" + os.sep + "blocks" + os.sep + "misc" + os.sep + "fountain1.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = pos[0]
        self.rect.y = pos[1]
        self.wImage = pygame.image.load("Images" + os.sep + "blocks" + os.sep + "misc" + os.sep + "fountain2.png").convert()
        self.wBoundingBox = self.wImage.get_rect()
        self.wBoundingBox.x = pos[0] + 25
        self.wBoundingBox.y = pos[1]

        self.waterOrigin = self.wBoundingBox.midbottom

        self.particles = {}
        create_particles()

    def create_particles(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.particles[i] = WaterParticle(self.name, self.wBoundingBox, self.waterOrigin)

    def draw_particles(self, screen):
        for particle in self.particles:
            particle.draw(screen)

    def update(self):
        self.draw_particles()
```

Comment: The error might be in Fountain. The traceback is referencing this line: self.block[name] = Fountain((x, y), name)

Comment: Show the Fountain class, where you add it too the sprite group

Comment: @M4rtini added the Fountain class

Comment: @ChristianCareaga added the Fountain class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling your init function `init` instead of `__init__`, the `Sprite` class will be called with `((x, y), name)`.

This probably leads to internal confusion - one of the "real" parameters might be used in a context where your arguments don't match.

Comment: Much more detailed than the other answer, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You've called the method "`init`" instead of "`__init__`".